# How to insert data into table using stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures

I am passing form values to stored procedure parameters and i have a problem...
I want to execute this stored procedure from a C# program.
 I am VERY new at this, so any help on why I am getting these errors is greatly appreciated.

## Stored Procedure Parameters

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[User] 
(
   @pname varchar(100),
   @Colour varchar(100),
   @Sheet varchar(100),
   @Size varchar(100),
   @GSM varchar(100),
   @pcost varchar(100),
   @is_deleted bit,
   @DOC datetime
)   
as begin 
INSERT INTO [SMjobcard].[dbo].[Papertype]
        ([pname]
       ,[Colour]
       ,[Sheet]
       ,[Size]
       ,[GSM]
       ,[pcost]
       ,[is_deleted]
       ,[DOC])
 VALUES
       (@pname,@Colour,@Sheet,@Size,@GSM,@pcost,@is_deleted,@DOC)
 END
```

### C#

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.OleDb;

public partial class Admin : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String ConnString =   ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnString);
    //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial    Catalog=SMjobcard;Integrated Security=True");
    //con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(ConnString);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "User";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pname", SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = TextBox2.Text.Trim();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Colour", SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = TextBox3.Text.Trim();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Sheet", SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = TextBox4.Text.Trim();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Size", SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = TextBox5.Text.Trim();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@GSM", SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = TextBox6.Text.Trim();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pcost", SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = TextBox7.Text.Trim();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@is_deleted", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = true;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DOC", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = TextBox9.Text.Trim();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        lblmsg.Text = "Record inserted successfully";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       ex.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }  
   }
}
```

** i have an error for converting string to decimal,string to Boolean,string to decimal plz help me **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your table design and then create the Stored Procedure.it may be possible that your are inserting wrong data to wrong column.means string data to bool column.so please check.